# MyBatis - getting table to object with one integer and list of integer

Tags: java, mybatis

I have following table:

```
IDofDog, IDOfOwner  
1         4
2         4
3         3
4         3
```

As you can see, one person can have more that one dogs.  I also have a class:

```
class A{
   int ownerID;
   List <Integer> dogs;
}
```

Is it possible to get for chosen owner (for example `4`) his dogs ?  More exactly I would like (using mybatis) get such `A a` object that:

```
a.ownerID = 4
a.dogs = [1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you might be able to do this with the `@Result` annotation. Something like...

```
interface DogRepo {

    @Select("Select distinct IdOfOwner as ownerId from DogOwnership")
    @Results(@Result(column = "ownerId", property = "dogs", many = @Many(select = "getDogIdsForOwner")))
    A getDogsByOwner();

    @Select("Select IdofDog from DogOwnership where IdOfOwner=#{ownerId}")
    List<Integer> getDogIdsForOwner(@Param("ownerId") int ownerId);
}
```

Probably not the most efficient way of doing it, it might be more efficient to just read the rows and manually build up your objects.

Comment: For getting a particular owner and their dogs, you can add `where IdOfOwner=#{ownerId}` to the first query (and a method parameter)

Comment: @HaskellFun I admit I have not run it, but I've seen something similar in another project before

Comment: `column = "ownerId"  ` What does it mean ? Does it tell that join is on this column ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Always found it hard to find the java doc for MyBATIS, but it looks like that's what the `column` attribute is for, yes